# How to do paginated API calls until reaching the end?

Tags: angularjs, recursion, soundcloud

I imagine this could be a pretty general problem, but in this case I'm using AngularJS and the SoundCloud API.

Here's the flow:

- Call `loadTracks()`
- `loadTracks()` should load the tracks of a SoundCloud user, 50 at a time, until the list runs out.
- `loadTracks()` does this by calling another function, `sc.getTracksByUser(id)`, which returns a promise
- `loadTracks()` should update the variable `$scope.tracks` with each 50 track batch when it arrives

The SoundCloud API provides an option `offset`, so loading the batches is relatively easy. I think it's the promise that is tripping me up. Without the promise, the solution would be:

```
$scope.tracks = [];

var loadTracks = function() {
    var page = -1,
        done = false,
        newTracks;

    while (!done) {
        newTracks = getFiftyTracks(page++);
        for (var i = 0; i < newTracks.length; i++) {
            $scope.tracks.push(newTracks[i]);
        }
        if (newTracks.length < 50) done = true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that line with `getFiftyTracks` in it is not how it works. The actual implementation (using a promise) is:

```
sc.getTracksByUser(id).then(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $scope.tracks.push(response[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the solution to this is some sort of recursion, but I'm not sure.

Comment: you haven't identified what the problem is. Where is declaration of `getTracksByUser`. Don't you need to pass a `page` to it?

Comment: How do you pass the page number or offset to getTracksByUser?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way

```
sc.getTracksByUser(id).then(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $scope.tracks.push(response[i]);
    }
  // if response return 50 track call getTracksByUser again
  if (response.length === 50) sc.getTracksByUser(id);

});
```